# Как убрать задержку при вещании потока?

Tags: wowza

День добрый. Решил вещать онлайн трансляцию по локальной сети. Но вот не задача. Даже в локальной сети задержка видео в ~5 секунд. У кого какие соображения как убрать задержку? может есть какие-либо настройки которые я не углядел =) Конфиг который я использую для live-потока сейчас:

```
<Root>
    <Application>
        <!-- Uncomment to set application level timeout values
        <ApplicationTimeout>60000</ApplicationTimeout>
        <PingTimeout>12000</PingTimeout>
        <ValidationFrequency>8000</ValidationFrequency>
        <MaximumPendingWriteBytes>0</MaximumPendingWriteBytes>
        <MaximumSetBufferTime>60000</MaximumSetBufferTime>
        <MaximumStorageDirDepth>25</MaximumStorageDirDepth>
        -->
        <Connections>
            <AutoAccept>true</AutoAccept>
            <AllowDomains></AllowDomains>
        </Connections>
        <!--
            StorageDir path variables

            ${com.wowza.wms.AppHome} - Application home directory
            ${com.wowza.wms.ConfigHome} - Configuration home directory
            ${com.wowza.wms.context.VHost} - Virtual host name
            ${com.wowza.wms.context.VHostConfigHome} - Virtual host config directory
            ${com.wowza.wms.context.Application} - Application name
            ${com.wowza.wms.context.ApplicationInstance} - Application instance name

        -->
        <Streams>
            <StreamType>live-record</StreamType>
            <StorageDir>${com.wowza.wms.context.VHostConfigHome}/content</StorageDir>
            <KeyDir>${com.wowza.wms.context.VHostConfigHome}/keys</KeyDir>
            <!-- LiveStreamPacketizers (separate with commas): cupertinostreamingpacketizer, smoothstreamingpacketizer, sanjosestreamingpacketizer, mpegdashstreamingpacketizer, cupertinostreamingrepeater, smoothstreamingrepeater, sanjosestreamingrepeater, dvrstreamingpacketizer, dvrstreamingrepeater -->
            <LiveStreamPacketizers></LiveStreamPacketizers>
            <!-- Properties defined here will override any properties defined in conf/Streams.xml for any streams types loaded by this application -->
            <Properties>
            </Properties>
        </Streams>
        <Transcoder>
            <!-- To turn on transcoder set to: transcoder -->
            <LiveStreamTranscoder></LiveStreamTranscoder>
            <!-- [templatename].xml or ${SourceStreamName}.xml -->
            <Templates>${SourceStreamName}.xml,transrate.xml</Templates>
            <ProfileDir>${com.wowza.wms.context.VHostConfigHome}/transcoder/profiles</ProfileDir>
            <TemplateDir>${com.wowza.wms.context.VHostConfigHome}/transcoder/templates</TemplateDir>
            <Properties>
            </Properties>
        </Transcoder>

        <DVR>
            <!-- As a single server or as an origin, use dvrstreamingpacketizer in LiveStreamPacketizers above -->
            <!-- Or, in an origin-edge configuration, edges use dvrstreamingrepeater in LiveStreamPacketizers above -->
            <!-- As an origin, also add dvrchunkstreaming to HTTPStreamers below -->

            <!-- If this is a dvrstreamingrepeater, define Application/Repeater/OriginURL to point back to the origin -->

            <!-- To turn on DVR recording set Recorders to dvrrecorder.  This works with dvrstreamingpacketizer  -->
            <Recorders></Recorders>

            <!-- As a single server or as an origin, set the Store to dvrfilestorage-->
            <!-- edges should have this empty -->
            <Store></Store>

            <!--  Window Duration is length of live DVR window in seconds.  0 means the window is never trimmed. -->
            <WindowDuration>0</WindowDuration>

            <!-- Storage Directory is top level location where dvr is stored.  e.g. c:/temp/dvr -->
            <StorageDir>${com.wowza.wms.context.VHostConfigHome}/dvr</StorageDir>

            <!-- valid ArchiveStrategy values are append, version, delete -->
            <ArchiveStrategy>append</ArchiveStrategy>

            <!-- Properties for DVR -->
            <Properties>
            </Properties>
        </DVR>

        <TimedText>
            <!-- VOD caption providers (separate with commas): vodcaptionprovidermp4_3gpp, vodcaptionproviderttml, vodcaptionproviderwebvtt,  vodcaptionprovidersrt, vodcaptionproviderscc -->
            <VODTimedTextProviders>vodcaptionprovidermp4_3gpp</VODTimedTextProviders>

            <!-- Properties for TimedText -->
            <Properties>
            </Properties>       
        </TimedText>

        <!-- HTTPStreamers (separate with commas): cupertinostreaming, smoothstreaming, sanjosestreaming, mpegdashstreaming, dvrchunkstreaming -->
        <HTTPStreamers>cupertinostreaming,smoothstreaming,sanjosestreaming</HTTPStreamers>
        <SharedObjects>
            <StorageDir></StorageDir>
        </SharedObjects>
        <Client>
            <IdleFrequency>-1</IdleFrequency>
            <Access>
                <StreamReadAccess>*</StreamReadAccess>
                <StreamWriteAccess>*</StreamWriteAccess>
                <StreamAudioSampleAccess></StreamAudioSampleAccess>
                <StreamVideoSampleAccess></StreamVideoSampleAccess>
                <SharedObjectReadAccess>*</SharedObjectReadAccess>
                <SharedObjectWriteAccess>*</SharedObjectWriteAccess>
            </Access>
        </Client>
        <RTP>
            <!-- RTP/Authentication/[type]Methods defined in Authentication.xml. Default setup includes; none, basic, digest -->
            <Authentication>
                <PublishMethod>digest</PublishMethod>
                <PlayMethod>none</PlayMethod>
            </Authentication>
            <!-- RTP/AVSyncMethod. Valid values are: senderreport, systemclock, rtptimecode -->
            <AVSyncMethod>systemclock</AVSyncMethod>
            <MaxRTCPWaitTime>12000</MaxRTCPWaitTime>
            <IdleFrequency>75</IdleFrequency>
            <RTSPSessionTimeout>90000</RTSPSessionTimeout>
            <RTSPMaximumPendingWriteBytes>0</RTSPMaximumPendingWriteBytes>
            <RTSPBindIpAddress></RTSPBindIpAddress>
            <RTSPConnectionIpAddress>0.0.0.0</RTSPConnectionIpAddress>
            <RTSPOriginIpAddress>127.0.0.1</RTSPOriginIpAddress>
            <IncomingDatagramPortRanges>*</IncomingDatagramPortRanges>
            <!-- Properties defined here will override any properties defined in conf/RTP.xml for any depacketizers loaded by this application -->
            <Properties>
            </Properties>
        </RTP>
        <MediaCaster>
            <RTP>
                <RTSP>
                    <!-- udp, interleave -->
                    <RTPTransportMode>interleave</RTPTransportMode>
                </RTSP>
            </RTP>
            <!-- Properties defined here will override any properties defined in conf/MediaCasters.xml for any MediaCasters loaded by this applications -->
            <Properties>
            </Properties>
        </MediaCaster>
        <MediaReader>
            <!-- Properties defined here will override any properties defined in conf/MediaReaders.xml for any MediaReaders loaded by this applications -->
            <Properties>
            </Properties>
        </MediaReader>
        <MediaWriter>
            <!-- Properties defined here will override any properties defined in conf/MediaWriter.xml for any MediaWriter loaded by this applications -->
            <Properties>
            </Properties>
        </MediaWriter>
        <LiveStreamPacketizer>
            <!-- Properties defined here will override any properties defined in conf/LiveStreamPacketizers.xml for any LiveStreamPacketizers loaded by this applications -->
            <Properties>
            </Properties>
        </LiveStreamPacketizer>
        <HTTPStreamer>
            <!-- Properties defined here will override any properties defined in conf/HTTPStreamers.xml for any HTTPStreamer loaded by this applications -->
            <Properties>
            </Properties>
        </HTTPStreamer>
        <Repeater>
            <OriginURL></OriginURL>
            <QueryString><![CDATA[]]></QueryString>
        </Repeater> 
        <Modules>
            <Module>
                <Name>base</Name>
                <Description>Base</Description>
                <Class>com.wowza.wms.module.ModuleCore</Class>
            </Module>
            <Module>
                <Name>logging</Name>
                <Description>Client Logging</Description>
                <Class>com.wowza.wms.module.ModuleClientLogging</Class>
            </Module>
            <Module>
                <Name>flvplayback</Name>
                <Description>FLVPlayback</Description>
                <Class>com.wowza.wms.module.ModuleFLVPlayback</Class>
            </Module> 
        </Modules>
        <!-- Properties defined here will be added to the IApplication.getProperties() and IApplicationInstance.getProperties() collections -->
        <Properties>
        </Properties>
    </Application>
</Root>
```

Comment: @lampa конвертируй в ответ, самый простой способ транслировать видео без задержки, это использовать в качестве плеера демонстрационный плеер DVR от Wowza =). Проблема была и в правду в буферизации.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня был затык в том, что я использовал плеер с буферизацией и по этому была задержка.

копнул свои исходники, параметр:

```
nsPublish.bufferTime = 0;
```

в флешке